# iphone app incorrectly including ipad nib

Tags: iphone, ipad, nib

Im working on a ipad and iphone app, it's not universal (two different app ids).

I have created one target for each version in xcode.

But I have a problem with my Main Interface, when I am running the iphone app in the ipad-simulator or real ipad, it is showing the ipad main interface. This is of course not working since the resources for the ipad interface is not included in the iphone target.

The nib files describing the ipad main interface is also not included in the iphone target. But when I browse the iphone application package the ipad nib files are there?

Any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same issue. I fixed by specifying the nib in the Info.plist :

Assuming that your xib files are: `MainWindow_iPhone.xib` and `MainWindow_iPad.xib`

- For the key: `NSMainNibFile` (Main nib file base name), give the value as `MainWindow_iPhone`
- For the key: `NSMainNibFile~ipad` (Main nib file base name (iPad)), give the value as `MainWindow_iPad`

Comment: Thanx for guiding me to the solution, I just deleted the NSMainNibFile~ipad entry from my iphone nib and then everything worked as it should.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your project -> Target (select one) -> Build phases -> Copy bundle resources   and see what your copying into each bundle.